# Como atribuir delimitador de quebra de linha de forma dinâmica

Tags: php

A minha dúvida seria se existe alguma função que eu possa usar nesse meu código de exemplo abaixo para que o próprio php se encarregue de  identificar que a cada dois conjuntos de valores existe uma quebra de linha sem que eu tenha que colocar o delimitador `&` manualmente no final de cada linha e que eu consiga obter o mesmo resultado que tive no exemplo.

O conjunto de valores que preciso adaptar a esse meu código vem separado só por vírgula:

```
 $str = "linha 1, linha 1, linha 2, linha 2, linha 3, linha 3";
```

**Meu código de exemplo:**

```
 $str = "
 linha 1, linha 1 &
 linha 2, linha 2 &
 linha 3, linha 3 &
 ";
 
 $arr= explode('&', $str); // transforma a string em array.
 
 $arrN = array();
 foreach($arr as $item){
     $valor = explode(',', $item); 
 
 echo $arrN[$valor[0]] = $valor[0] . $valor[1]. "<br>";    
     
 
   
 }
```

**Resultado:**

linha 1 linha 1

linha 2 linha 2

linha 3 linha 3

Comment: você tem essa `string` ordenada e nesse padrão sempre? porque nem precisa colocar um & para isso!

Comment: os valores mudam, a ordem sempre é a mesma uma linha e duas colunas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

poder ser realizado com um for dessa forma.

```
<?php
$str = "linha 1, linha 1, linha 2, linha 2, linha 3, linha 3";
 
$arr= explode(',', $str); // transforma a string em array.
 
for($i =0;$i< count($arr);$i = $i + 2){
    
 echo  $arr[$i] . $arr[$i+1]. "<br>";
}
```

também pode adicionar a virgula na string

```
<?php
$str = "linha 1, linha 1, linha 2, linha 2, linha 3, linha 3";
 
$arr= explode(',', $str); // transforma a string em array.
 
for($i =0;$i< count($arr);$i = $i + 2){
    
 echo  $arr[$i]. ",". $arr[$i+1]. "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Gostei da sua resposta mais só mais uma coisa..se caso os valores viessem assim: $str = "linha 1, linha 1 linha 2, linha 2 linha 3, linha 3";  teria algum jeito de tratar isso?

Comment: e preciso alguma referencia para gerar o array uma boa pratica seria utilizar | para dividir os campos ou no exemplo acima com a , espaço em branco pode ser utilizado em vários locais gerando retorno indesejável